# Extract ordered point coordinates from polygon layer via Virtual Layer or PostGIS View

Tags: qgis, postgis, virtual-layer

I have polygon layer and I need to create table with XY coordinates for each polygon staring from farthest to west (lowest value of X).
Now I have Virtual Layer with

```
SELECT ST_DissolvePoints(geometry) AS geom, id
FROM "poly"
```

next I use processing to change multipart to singlepart layer I export them to CSV with XY coordinates and then I order them manually in excel.

Preferred solution is to have virtual layer with already ordered points but if solution with POSTGIS view will be good enough.